# Вычитание из диапазона дат другого диапазона

Tags: sql, oracle

Как получить набор строк получаемых при пересечении одного диапазона дат другим?

Например диапазон:

```
01.01.2020 - 24.06.2020`
```

пересекается с:

```
01.05.2020 - 31.05.2020
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
01.01.2020 - 30.04.2020 01.06.2020 - 24.04.2020
```

Comment: Выложите CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с образцом данных (3-5 записей и требуемый для таких данных результат). Предусмотрите ВСЕ варианты отношений (внутреннее вхождение, частичное перекрытие, касание и пр.)

Answer (score 3):

Можно так ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ed78da2d322f56b618dc6f1bcdb20bd)):

```
select 
    min (l.dt)||'-'||max (l.dt) lower, 
    min (u.dt)||'-'||max (u.dt) upper
from t1 l cross join t1 u 
cross join (select min (dt) lb, max (dt) ub from t2) 
where l.dt < lb
and   u.dt > ub
```

Результат:

```
LOWER                 UPPER                
--------------------- ---------------------
01.01.2020-30.04.2020 01.06.2020-24.06.2020
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Я немного подправил условие. Если можно, прокомментируйте решение согласно внесенным правкам.

Comment: @pr5 Пожалуйста, не изменяйте условие задачи после того, как вам дали ответ. Задайте просто новый вопрос.

Comment: @pr5, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)